# vector and matrix multiplication using function

Tags: python

I am new in python, and I want to write a code to multiply vector to matrix through function. For example vector dimension(2) and matrix dimension(2x2) . Let me to explain my idea as follow:

```
# Declare function for vector
def v():
  m=[1,2]
# Declare function for matrix
def m():
  m=[[1,0],[0,1]]
# Multiply vector to matrix
def process():
  new_matrix=v()*m()
# print output
def out():
  print(new_matrix)
```

I tried to write like above code,but I didn't success, please could any one help me ?

Comment: Your code has multiple problems. Work on them one at a time. The biggest problem is your bad indentation, which is critical in Python. The lines inside a function must be indented. The second problem is that you don't understand how to pass information in to and out of a function. Look up those two things, edit your code appropriately, then check if you still have a problem.

Comment: Yes I agree with you I don't know how to pass information in and out of the function, I tried several approach but I didn't know how.

Comment: Why do you need those functions at all here? Just remove all those `def` lines--the remaining lines perform one or two purposes and make a perfectly good section of code without other functions. Removing those also simplifies the indentation. Your next problem is the re-use of the variable name `m` for two values. The second value just overwrites the first one, which is lost. Use two different variable, such as `v` for the vector and `m` for the matrix. Make those changes and get back to us.